# What is the best Cache plugin that works with paypal IPN?

Tags: caching, plugins, paypal

Can you please get some suggestions for a Cache plugin that will work well with PayPal IPN for instant downloads after shopping?

thank you

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Cache has nothing to do with IPN or delivering electronic goods.

Comment: Sorry it too me so long to answer back. I had read about some cache plugin can block paypal ipn and was trying to find a good cache plug in to use.  I was really lost when I posted this but decided the article I read was not a good source.